# Beamer compilation error, ps error

Tags: beamer, compiling, ps

I have a presentation in beamer and I've used the trick with overlays, the one I asked about here.

And in other presentation everything worked. I compiled the document, first to dvi, and then to ps, but when I want to create pdf from ps (either via ps2pdf or Adobe distiller) I get the error:

```
%%[ Warning: Helvetica not found, using Font Substitution. Font cannot be embedded. ]%%
%%[ Warning: Times-Italic not found, using Font Substitution. Font cannot be embedded. ]%%
%%[ Error: syntaxerror; OffendingCommand: ? ]%%
%%[ Flushing: rest of job (to end-of-file) will be ignored ]%%
%%[ Warning: PostScript error. No PDF file produced. ] %%
```

MWE is:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,mathserif,12pt]{beamer} 
\usecolortheme[named=Emerald]{structure} 
\useoutertheme{infolines} 
\usetheme[height=7mm]{Rochester} 
\setbeamertemplate{items}[ball] 
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true] 
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
%\usefonttheme{serif}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}



\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{time}
\usepackage{extarrows}





\title{Random title}
\subtitle{Random subtitle}
\author{}
\institute[Random institute]{Random institute}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle



\begin{frame}
\frametitle{About}
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item something something\pause
    \centerline{\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{1graf.eps}}\pause
    \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item bla\pause
    \item bla
    \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

It worked before, I dk what's wrong now :\

If I try with dvipdfm it messes up the image, if I try with pdflatex the picture won't show because it's .eps.

What's wrong, and what should I do? :(

EDIT: oh and when I make dvips in texmakerx it gives out:

```
Process started

This is dvips(k) 5.99 Copyright 2010 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com) ' TeX output 2011.06.04:1347' -> prezproba.ps <C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\pk\ljfour\public\bbm\dpi600\bbm12.pk> <C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/dvips/base/tex.pro> <C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/fontname/8r.enc> <C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/dvips/base/texps.pro> <C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/dvips/base/special.pro> <C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/dvips/base/color.pro>. <C:/Users/Denis/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/fonts/type1/public/txfonts/txsy.pfb> <C:/Users/Denis/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/fonts/type1/public/txfonts/rtxmi.pfb> <C:/Users/Denis/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/fonts/type1/public/txfonts/rtxr.pfb> [1] [2<1graf.eps><D:/LaTeX/1graf.eps>

dvips: expected to see %%EndBinary at end of data; struggling on ] [3<1graf.eps><D:/LaTeX/1graf.eps>

dvips: expected to see %%EndBinary at end of data; struggling on ] [4<1graf.eps><D:/LaTeX/1graf.eps>

dvips: expected to see %%EndBinary at end of data; struggling on ] [5<1graf.eps><D:/LaTeX/1graf.eps>

dvips: expected to see %%EndBinary at end of data; struggling on ] [6<1graf.eps><D:/LaTeX/1graf.eps>

dvips: expected to see %%EndBinary at end of data; struggling on ] [7<1graf.eps><D:/LaTeX/1graf.eps>

dvips: expected to see %%EndBinary at end of data; struggling on ]

Process exited normally
```

Comment: Convert the picture into pdf, there are many utilities; TeX Live and MiKTeX have `epstopdf`.

Comment: @dingo_d: your presentation used PSTricks ? If no PSTricks, then try to compile it using pdfLaTeX rather than your current step using `latex.exe->dvips->ps2pdf` to convert `dvi->ps->pdf`. Don't forget to convert the `*.eps` to `.pdf` as already mentioned by @egreg.

Comment: @dingo_d: your code above cannot be regarded as MWE.  :-)

Comment: Will the picture retain all the properties as in .eps? Because I know if I put .png picture I need to set up bounding box and stuff, and .eps pictures have that included in them...

Comment: Yay, I need to define bounding box, and overlay don't want to work -.-" 

And this is totally bizarre since compiling the other presentation which has .eps figures in it, via dvi->ps and then with Adobe Distiller into pdf works flawlessly :\

Comment: Ok, it seems that something is wrong with those eps pictures :\ Some work, while others won't... Plus the overlay is totally messed up -.-"